# How to convert large integers to base 2^32?

Tags: c++, largenumber

First off, I'm doing this for myself so please don't suggest "use GMP / xint / bignum" (if it even applies).

I'm looking for a way to convert large integers (say, OVER 9000 digits) into a int32 array of 2<sup>32</sup> representations. The numbers will start out as base 10 strings.

For example, if I wanted to convert `string a = "4294967300"` (in base 10), which is just over `INT_MAX`, to the new base 2<sup>32</sup> array, it would be `int32_t b[] = {1,5}`. If `int32_t b[] = {3,2485738}`, the base 10 number would be `3 * 2^32 + 2485738`. Obviously the numbers I'll be working with are beyond the range of even int64 so I can't exactly turn the string into an integer and mod my way to success.

I have a function that does subtraction in base 10. Right now I'm thinking I'll just do `subtraction(char* number, "2^32")` and count how many times before I get a negative number, but that will probably take a long time for larger numbers.

Can someone suggest a different method of conversion? Thanks.

**EDIT**
Sorry in case you didn't see the tag, I'm working in **C++**

Comment: How are your long division skills?

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn: Why? Did I convert it wrong? My brain doesn't work too well with bases other than base 10.

Comment: @sth128 no i think he's implying that doing the conversion from the base 10 string to your base32 int array requires alot of long division skills

Comment: I don't think Michael is right though, going from a base32 to base10, _that_ takes division.

Comment: Define a bignum type (dynamic array of int32_t). Define operator* and operator+ for the type. use "long multiplication". Reconstruct it from string the same way you would reconstruct int32_t from string. You do know, how to manually convert string to int, right? It works the same way for any integer. The only things you really need to make int from string are addition and multiplication operators.

Comment: @MooingDuck, not base32, base2^32, i.e. base4294967296.

Comment: @MooingDuck: division isn't truly necessary. Shifts, adds and `decimal adjust after addition (AKA DAA)` will do. See an example [here](http://www.smspower.org/Development/BinaryCodedDecimal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your bignum class already has multiplication and addition, it's fairly simple:

```
 bignum str_to_big(char* str) {
     bignum result(0);
     while (*str) {
         result *= 10;
         result += (*str - '0');
         str = str + 1;
     }
     return result;
 }
```

Converting the other way is the same concept, but requires division and modulo

```
std::string big_to_str(bignum num) {
    std::string result;
    do {
        result.push_back(num%10);
        num /= 10;
    } while(num > 0);
    std::reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
    return result;
}
```

Both of these are for unsigned only.

Comment: Init result to 0, then change `str *= 10;` to `result *= 10;` and `str += (*str - '0');` to `result += (*str - '0');`

Comment: push_back() will append at the end of the string. But you need to insert at the beginning because you're getting the last digits first. Or you could reverse the string at the very end.

Comment: Alex: I've done this many many times, but of course when I put it on the _internet_ I mess everything up...  (thanks for the fixes)

Comment: I think I don't actually have the required knowledge to understand your code. Wouldn't `while(*str)` exit when the cell is not 1? Also, as far as I can see, this function simply converts a string of single digits into a `bignum` integer, where as I need it to turn into an array of int32, each cell having the ceiling of `INT_MAX`. This left-to-right operation would not really work?

Comment: @sth128: I was working with a pretend bignum that holds/is an array of int32.  You can use my loading algorithm with DPO's mulbig and addbig.  This is all much easier once you learn classes/structs.  Read more in your/a C++ book.

Answer (score 1):

To convert from base 10 strings to your numbering system, starting with zero continue adding and multiplying each base 10 digit by 10. Every time you have a carry add a new digit to your base 2^32 array.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest (not the most efficient) way to do this is to write two functions, one to multiply a large number by an int, and one to add an int to a large number.  If you ignore the complexities introduced by signed numbers, the code looks something like this:

(EDITED to use `vector` for clarity and to add code for actual question)

```
void mulbig(vector<uint32_t> &bignum, uint16_t multiplicand)
{
    uint32_t carry=0;
    for( unsigned i=0; i<bignum.size(); i++ ) {
        uint64_t r=((uint64_t)bignum[i] * multiplicand) + carry;
        bignum[i]=(uint32_t)(r&0xffffffff);
        carry=(uint32_t)(r>>32);
    }
    if( carry )
        bignum.push_back(carry);
}

void addbig(vector<uint32_t> &bignum, uint16_t addend)
{
    uint32_t carry=addend;
    for( unsigned i=0; carry && i<bignum.size(); i++ ) {
        uint64_t r=(uint64_t)bignum[i]  + carry;
        bignum[i]=(uint32_t)(r&0xffffffff);
        carry=(uint32_t)(r>>32);
    }
    if( carry )
        bignum.push_back(carry);
}
```

Then, implementing atobignum() using those functions is trivial:

```
void atobignum(const char *str,vector<uint32_t> &bignum)
{
    bignum.clear();
    bignum.push_back(0);
    while( *str ) {
        mulbig(bignum,10);
        addbig(bignum,*str-'0');
        ++str;
    }
}
```

Comment: `assume infinite space for number storage`, and an infinitely fast computer so that the next function can run...  Anyway the concept is perfect, you just need to make it stop when it reaches the end of the array.

Comment: The condition in `while(*bignum || carry)` is wrong w.r.t. *bignum. The while loop can stop too early when it hits *bignum==0 and carry==0. Consider multiplying 0x100000000 by 2. The loop body won't execute at all in this case. You need to distinguish between a zero digit (that is, *bignum==0) and the last, most significant digit, which you can't with such a design.

Comment: Gah.  You are, of course, correct.  Examples edited to work a bit better in a real context, at the expense of some speed and use of STL.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Docjar: gnu/java/math/MPN.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/gnu/java/math/MPN.java.html) might contain what you're looking for, specifically the code for `public static int set_str (int dest[], byte[] str, int str_len, int base)`.

Answer (score 0):

Start by converting the number to binary. Starting from the right, each group of 32 bits is a single base2^32 digit.

Comment: that sounds overly complicated.

Comment: How do I circumvent the int32 / int64 byte limit?

Comment: @sth128, I don't see how you can use normal integer types here. You'll need to figure out your own representation for very large numbers, such as strings, or else use one that someone else has created, like bignum. My answer above is a half-joke -- it might not be the most efficient way to do things, but it's probably the easiest to conceptualize.

Comment: @Caleb: I did write a bunch of functions to represent huge numbers. It's in the format of a char array with the last cell being `'+'` or `'-'` (guess what they do). However each cell represents a base 10 decimal digit (eg. `'1234+'` means positive 1234 in base 10). Doing arithmetic in base 10 is extremely slow and someone on this site suggested that I convert the `char` array to `int32` array with each cell representing a base 2^32 (`4 billion) digit (so when a cell reaches 2^32, it carries over to the next).